# php convert stdClass object to array

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

Could anyone shed any light as to why I can get this working.
I want to query an array to see if the `USER->id` that is currently logged in is assigned a specific role:

```
$contextroles = get_records_sql("SELECT userid FROM {$CFG->prefix}role_assignments WHERE contextid = 23 AND roleid = 3");

function object2array($object) {
    if (is_object($object)) {
        foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    else {
        $array = $object;
    }
    return $array;
}

$alloweduser = object2array($contextroles);

if (in_array($USER->id, $alloweduser)) {
    echo'Your in<br />';
    echo $USER->id.'<br />';
    print_r($alloweduser);
}
else{
    echo'<br />You do not have permission to acces this database.<br />';
    echo $USER->id.'<br />';
    print_r($alloweduser);
    exit;
}
```

Im currently getting this output:

> You do not have permission to acces this database.
>
> 5410
>
> Array ( [7] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 7 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 9 ) [27] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 27 ) [98] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 98 ) [203] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 203 ) [252] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 252 ) [5410] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 5410 ) )

As you can see 5410 is in the array so should not get accessed denied.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: where is this variable/object `$USER, $CFG` come from? And what's wrong with object which you MUST convert it to array?

Comment: Your `object2array()` function is redundant. Casting an object to `(array)` has the same effect.

Comment: You're not saying, what the `get_records_sql()` does. Maybe you can just modify it so that it returns an array? What is `$USER->id`? And additionally I'm not sure if you can do a `foreach` on an object.

Also, "5410" is not in the array but rather another `stdObject` which holds the userid "5410". That's a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `5410 != stdClass Object ( [userid] => 5410 )` if you use `in_array()`.

Since your array key looks like same with `userid`, you just use `isset($alloweduser[$USER->id])` instead.

Comment: also removed function: Your object2array() function is redundant. Casting an object to (array) has the same effect. – Rijk van Wel 2

Comment: @Codded Instead of `isset()`, use `array_key_exists($USER->id,$alloweduser);`